# Magento 1.9 - Ajax Add to Cart from category page/product listing

Tags: ajax, magento, magento-1.9

I have installed the Amasty plugin Ajax Add to Cart which works fine from the product page but I want it to work on the product listing pages. I want it so that you can add any product on the fly from the category. Is there something I need to do to get this working?

My button for each product is:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for using Amasty extension!

Adding products to cart from categories is available out of the box in our Ajax Shopping Cart module. So it should work fine. Please submit a ticket to our support team and we will investigate why this feature doesn't work on your site https://amasty.com/contacts/

Comment: I am having the same issue can you please help me.